# Hesped after the burial?

Tags: death

Is there anything wrong with giving a public hesped for an "average" person on their sheloshim.
I saw in [halachapedia](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Hesped)

that "

> Generally the eulogy is always before the burial. However, for a
>   talmid chacham the eulogies can continue throughout shiva, for a gadol
>   it could continue to shloshim and for a gadol hador it could continue
>   for twelve months

"
This is sourced as  Shulchan Aruch YD 344:18, Gesher Hachaim 1:13:5

this would seem to imply that for an "average" person there shoudl NOT be eulogies after the burial
I haven't looked up the sources, Does anyone know why?  My LOR said it's OK for me to say for my father at his sheloshim - but I don't want do any damage by doing so.

OR 
perhaps the above quote means that for the gedolim we give hespedim *throughout* those periods (e.g. each day of the sheloshim).  But doesn't mean to imply that it's forbidden outside of these period for an "ad-hoc" hesped.  But rather can be done (though only during the 12 months) see [here](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/laws-of-hespedeulogies/#_ftnref12) from the "Taz 344/5 in name of Ramban in Toras Hadam; Chachmas Adam 155/17"

(i.e. Are there those that learn the Shulchan Aruch differently and not in line with this view from the Taz/Chayei Adam )?

thx